# Second recyclerview is not scrolling smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a bottom sheet in android with two recycler views parallel to each other in constraint layout. The first recycler view scrolls smoothly but the second on does not scrolls or scrolls after many swipes.
I want to scroll both recycler views smoothly.[Here is the screenshot of recycler views in bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Qut.png)

Here is my **xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/leftGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/leftInnerGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.03" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/rightInnerGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/rightGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/centerGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottomGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topBackground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pickText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick Up"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/selectedDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topBackground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectedDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tomorrow, Between 11:00am - 12:00pm"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/topBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pickText" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/selectedDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/pickText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topBackground" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/timeRecyclerView"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/centerGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftInnerGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/daysRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/centerGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightInnerGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my **java** class:

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    RecyclerView timeRecyclerView, daysRecyclerView;


    private ArrayList<DaysModal> daysModalArrayList;
    private DaysAdapter adapter;

    private String[] day = new String[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    private String[] date = new String[]{"21 Oct", "22 Oct", "23 Oct", "24 Oct", "25 Oct", "26 Oct", "27 Oct"};
    private int[] background = new int[]{R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow};


    private ArrayList<TimeModal> timeModalArrayList;
    private TimeAdapter timeAdapter;

    private String[] time = new String[]{
            "08:00am - 09:00am", "09:00am - 10:00am", "10:00am - 11:00am",
            "11:00am - 12:00pm", "12:00pm - 01:00pm", "01:00pm - 02:00pm",
            "02:00pm - 03:00pm", "03:00pm - 04:00pm", "04:00pm - 05:00pm",
            "05:00pm - 06:00pm", "06:00pm - 07:00pm", "07:00pm - 08:00pm"
    };
    private int[] timeBackground = new int[]{
            R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow,
            R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow,
            R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow,
            R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow,
            R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow,
            R.drawable.white_shadow, R.drawable.white_shadow
    };


    String selectedButton;

    public static BottomSheet getInstance() {
        return new BottomSheet();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);
        selectedButton = this.getArguments().getString("selectedButton");
        daysRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.daysRecyclerView);
        timeRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.timeRecyclerView);
        timeModalArrayList = displayTimes();
        timeAdapter = new TimeAdapter(getActivity(), timeModalArrayList);
        timeRecyclerView.setAdapter(timeAdapter);
        timeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));


        daysModalArrayList = displayDays();
        adapter = new DaysAdapter(getActivity(), daysModalArrayList);
        daysRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        daysRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));



        return view;
    }


    private ArrayList<DaysModal> displayDays() {
        ArrayList<DaysModal> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
            DaysModal daysModal = new DaysModal();
            daysModal.setDayOfTheWeek(day[i]);
            daysModal.setDate(date[i]);
            daysModal.setBackground(background[i]);
            list.add(daysModal);
        }
        return list;
    }


    private ArrayList<TimeModal> displayTimes() {
        ArrayList<TimeModal> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
            TimeModal timeModal = new TimeModal();
            timeModal.setTime(time[i]);
            timeModal.setBackground(timeBackground[i]);
            list.add(timeModal);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```